# Sad [Addons] ? Sad un's!

Tags: discussion

[addons](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/addons) - even the description is terrible.

I propose it's nuked, because grouping questions by the fact they are about an add on for another program, is really not useful for any kind of searching at all.

We don't do software recommendations, so it's not even useful in that regard.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one.  Add-ons are a class of software.  For any given application, familiarity with the add-ons is likely to be somewhat specialized knowledge.  The tag provides useful context, and might affect who responds on the application tag.  Even though it's meta, I'd be inclined to leave it.

Comment: If addons is kept, it should require a tag showing what the "addon" is added on to. @fixer1234 I'm sure there are experts in addons for Firefox, or for Excel, or for Eclipse, and so forth. Such people understand how the base package works, and how addons can be used to increase its functionality. However, I doubt there are very many experts in _addons_ as field of its own. I don't think we'll find many people who use the addons tag as the primary filter in a search, rather they might use it as a filter to a primary search in Apache, for example.

Comment: So [tag:excel-addon] or [tag:firefox-addon] then....

Comment: Many add-ons work with a software category, e.g., an add-on will work with many of the major browsers.  It would get excessively granular to have a tag for each major application that takes add-ons.  A more practical approach would be a few higher-level tags, like [browser-addon], [spreadsheet-addon], etc.; a tag for the application type (which would be used in combination with the application tag anyway).  Many users are familiar with more than one program of a type, so this would do an adequate job of separating expertise.  We can re-tag the most common ones and then see what's left.